# Overhead in websocket payload for binaryjs with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have implemented an application which sends multimedia content via websocket.
I've observed, by analysing the traffic with wireshark, that the payload sending the same content with http and websocket differs. 
For websocket, the payload is always exactly 6 bytes larger than for http. (The headers are obviously completely different, what is clear.)

I implemented it on javascript using Node.js with the module binaryjs on the server.

Either Node.js or binaryjs library adds 5 bytes at the beginning of the multimedia data (it looks like 0x93 0x02 0xda 0x5e 0xcb) and 1 more byte at the end of it (it looks like 0x15).
Any idea where this overhead may come from?

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/lib/client.js#L75) binaryjs is wrapping data chunks in 'messages' that add some meta data.

Comment: websockets useses a "data:" prefix and a newline postfix

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Then should it be binaryjs adding the metadata or should this happen for every websocket implementation? 
@dandavis, how do those prefix and postfix look like (how many bytes and which)?

Comment: situation normal; read the websockets draft for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As robertklep said the overhead you mention is because of metadata. binarypack which is used by binaryjs in serializing/deserializing (or packing/unpacking) binary data adds those bytes. binarypack uses much of [messagepack](http://msgpack.org/) specs and adds a few extra.

The function likely adding those extra bytes is `pack_bin` which works for binary files. You can see that [here](https://github.com/binaryjs/js-binarypack/blob/master/lib/binarypack.js#L316).